# Float values inferred as null during RDD to DF conversion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert the following RDD.take(1) to dataframe,

```python
[(697, [7, 7, 0.368, 1, 1, 0, 0.879]), (403, [1, 1, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4]), (485, [3, 4, 0.062, 1, 1, 0, 0.372])])]
```

using

```python
rdd.map(lambda p: get_m(slist)).toDF().show(1,False)
```

get_m returns a sorted list

```python
sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][6], reverse = True)[0:3]
```

This results in,

```python
|[[697,WrappedArray(7, 7, null, 1, 1, 0, null)],[403,WrappedArray(1, 1, null, 0, 0, 0, null)],[485,WrappedArray(3, 4, null, 1, 1, 0, null)]]
```

all my float values are auto-inferred as nulls

So, I tried to use my own schema as follows:

```python
field1 = [
StructField("x1", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("x2", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("x3", FloatType(), True),
StructField("x4", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("x5", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("x6", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("x7", FloatType(), True)
]

field2 = StructType([
StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("result", StructType(field1), True)
])

schema = StructType([
StructField("match_1", StructType(field2), True),
StructField("match_2", StructType(field2), True),
StructField("match_3", StructType(field2), True)
])
```

But this doesn't work - I get an error stating structfiled is not interable. I also tried to unpack using Row(**). None of them works. It looks like the way I've written the structtype is wrong. Ideally, I want a dataframe like,

```python
 id | results

697 | [1,1,0,1,5,4.3]

403 | [1,1,0.6,1,2,4.5]

485 | [1,1,0,1,0,9.3]
```

Comment: your expected output does not match your example data; is it acceptable to have all the values in your array col as `float` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark `arrays` have to contain values of a single type and a `list` of Python `ints` and `floats` doesn't satisfy this requirement. Since schema inference checks only the first element, it assumes it is `array<integer>` and treats all other values as invalid.

You should convert all values to `floats` before converting to `DataFrame`.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(697, [1,1,0,1,5,4.3])])
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], [float(v) for v in x[1]])).toDF()
```

If you want to keep mixed types, and all lists are of the same size, you can use `tuple` in place of list:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], tuple(x[1]))).toDF()
```